# Chrome and Safari on MacOS display wrong colors. Firefox works

Tags: macos, google-chrome, colors, safari

Okay. So I set the color of a background div to: rgb(0, 163, 140)

According to "Digital Colour Meter" I get the correct value in Firefox: rgb(0, 163, 140)

This is what I see in Chrome and Safari however: rgb(71, 160, 141)

What the heck? I tried different color profiles in Chrome using "force color profile" but that did not change anything. I tried two different MacBooks on the latest MacOS Mojave.

I found a couple of threads here on StackOverflow but no solution whatsoever. There has to be some kind of workaround?!

Comment: Are you sure there are no other CSS files overwriting your code?
Also, have you tryed using exadecimal instead of rgb?

Comment: I tried both hexadecimal and rgb. I inspected the code and both browsers choose exactly the same (correct) color. They just display it differently.

Comment: I checked some forums and they say that pasting "chrome://flags/#enable-gpu-rasterization" into the address bar could fix the issue.

Comment: Also, are you sure that there is no background reflecting the colors?
If you have set a lower opacity there could be something reflecting the color and making it look different due to the browser background change

Comment: GPU rasterization didn't change anything either. If I set my display color profile to sRGB then it works perfectly fine by the way. But then a lot of colors look over-saturated in general.

Comment: Oh okay, if that's the case it is probably because of the "safe colors".
The majority of the colors are safe, means that you can use them on every browser and have no problem at all. Some colors tho are not "safe" and won't be displayed equally on every browser

Comment: @Synapsis nope, I just tried a safe color and the difference is huge between Firefox and Chrome with my standard color profile.

Comment: Colours still different in 2021, firefox is correct (nice and bright, same as the illustrator design file) chrome and safari are quite a bit duller. I even enabled the 'force color profile: srgb' in Chrome and it is still duller (iMac monitor)

Answer (score 1):

Okay so, 
I made some researches about that and looks like this is a known issue and it's displayed here: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=44872

The only solution seems to be using a different color that gets displayed the same in different browsers 
Example:  Chrome renders #FF3A00 as #FF0000 so you could just use #FF0000.
Still, if someone has a rgb setting on its display it will still show as a different color for that.

It's your choiche to adapt the colors or just leave them like that, sadly you can't fix that even in the 20th century :)

Comment: And where do I find these colors? I tried one of these: http://www.elizabethcastro.com/html4_4e/examples/appendices/colorcharthex.html

And it did not work. The difference between Chrome and Firefox is huge.

Comment: Also, the link you provided - I already saw that. I have a completely different case here however, because the colors are not more saturated but washed out. They are more saturated in Firefox.

Comment: @Hillcow try to use simple colors as "red", "green", don't use exadecimal or rgb

Comment: Same difference even with these simple colors.

Comment: Oh... well then.. I'll let you know if I find something

Comment: That linked issue is from 2010. Not sure if there's a browser bug, but in Chrome I had to set force-color-profile to sRGB to match colors of Firefox in Linux, so I filed two new issues (not sure which browser has the issue): https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1133990 and https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1668444